# LinkedIn API to search public posts based on Hashtag

Tags: linkedin-api

Hashtags become more and more popular on LinkedIn:

- https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/71587/adding-hashtags-in-your-articles?lang=en
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hashtags-linkedin-directory-list-who-what-where-when-how-amy-jones/

Is LinkedIn plan to deliver an **API to search public posts based on hashtag**?

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything similar to this available now in 2022? I wanted to fetch public LinkedIn posts based on hashtags using Python, but I am not sure if it is possible now?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is possible since Microsoft took over and redid the API in May 2018. You can look at the limited schema and object types here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2

I would imagine that they stopped this practice because if people are reading LinkedIn posts on YOUR website, they are not trapped in LinkedIn's walled-in ad garden, and not making LinkedIn any money.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
It could be done as other plateformes allow to search and use their content. See Twitter, Instagram, Facebook, ...
They could force some constraints (rate limit, display constraints, ...) ...
But anyway, has you say, it's not possible ... yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this type of query. The LinkedIn API does not allow this kind of query.

Here are all the stuff you can do with it: https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it's not possible. My question was about any information about a potential roadmap for the release of that feature.

Comment: You can do it with a bot which scraps the desired content of any page.

Comment: scrapping is not a viable solution when you want to run a business based on their API :)

Comment: Yeah it depends of your project. However LinkedIn filters the data they wanna share in their API. So you may not have the choice.